# Running a form for only once in entire Windows form application lifetime

Tags: c#, winforms

In my project i want to show a user-guide when the user first installs my software.So, for `only one time` i want to show (at beginning) a window where some direction is given so that a user can understand in first time how to use my software.After the user once watches the window(user guide) this window will not appear further time.
I want to use a form like `userguid.cs`. this will show in the begging of the mainwindow for one time in the life of the my application. 
N:B: For example if user restart his computer and again run the app it will not show the userguide window again as it shows before
How can i do that?? Can anyone give idea how can i do that???

Comment: one way is to show that user guide and increment a flag variable, next time check that variable if it is 1 or 0, skip showing that guide.

Comment: What is your problem anyway? Showing form? Saving settings? Reading settings? There are numerous ways to achieve your goal.

Comment: And you can persist the flag value Anand mentioned in the registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply maintain a flag, which will help you store, whether the user guide has been displayed or not.

The flag can be a file, which is stored in your application directory, or if you have a database, you can store the boolean value in a db.

Then call the function to display the user guide, when the form loads, or wherever you require.

```
public void Form1_Load() {
   displayUserGuide();
}
```

And, in the function displayUserGuide see whether flag has been set or not.

```
public void displayUserGuide() {
  //Return, if the form has already been displayed.
  if(File.Exists("UGUID")) return;
  userGuide.Show();
  File.Create("UGUID");
}
```

You can simply call the function`displayUserGuide()` any where you want throughout the Application. The function will make sure the form is displayed only once.

In this way you can display Windows form application once.

Hope this helps!

Comment: but i want to run for once in the whole life time of the user.For example if user restart his computer and again run the app it will not show the userguide window again as it shows before.

Comment: When you run once, the user guide is displayed and the file is created in app folder. The next time you run the app, since the file is already present, the form isnt displayed. This is definitely for the lifetime of the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dummy file in the application path to make sure whether userguide displayed or not.

For Example,

Before loading UserGuide.cs, check for the following,

```
if(!File.Exists("UserGuideShown"))
{

  UserGuide.Show();
  File.Create("UserGuideShown");
}
```

When next time, the application loads, it will check for the file, it will be exists as it shown already. so it will skip showing up..

Comment: I would prefer to maintain this in your user-specific application settings, not by writing a file to disk. Not only is that a more elegant solution, your approach would quickly run afoul of UAC and other permissions-based restrictions. Regular users do not and should not have write permissions on the application's directory.